# Testing my Coturn server yielded in a 701 error stating that my "STUN server address is incompatible."

Tags: webrtc

I used the TrickleIce online tool to test my Coturn server and I received a 701 error informing me that "STUN server address is incompatible" and that "STUN binding request timed out."

I followed each step in this guide exactly to set up my Coturn server: https://gabrieltanner.org/blog/turn-server/

I don't understand what could be wrong. My config file contains everything the guide told me to add.

Is there other ways that I should test my Coturn server in the case that TrickleIce is an unreliable tool?

Comment: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/ works well. What will help you make progress is inspecting the status of your coturn instance. Is it running? Is it listening on the expected ports? Are those ports reachable from the public Internet? Is it receiving the STUN Binding requests from the test tool? Is the testing tool timing out? etc.